# Is two instances of the Windows Explorer normal

Tags: windows-explorer, virus

Sometimes I spot two instances of explorer.exe in the Tash Manager. Is there a need to run instances of explorer.exe in any case? Or this is some unusual malicious behavior??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fine, regular explorer windows and the taskbar are both `explorer.exe`, but run as separate instances so that one crashing doesn't take down the other.

Comment: thnx...now I don't have to wry anymore

Answer (score 2):

There's not a need for it as such. You can chose which behaviour you prefer;

```
Tools, Folder options, check/uncheck "Launch folder windows in a different process".
```

Comment: I don't have this option on